# Need assistance with reading module on windows machine using readdirSync and Sequelize

Tags: node.js, module, es6-modules

I have encountered the following problem reading modules from the same directory. This is a working project on mac and unix but encountered issues working on windows.

node version is: v16.16.0, I have even tried nvm and loading different versions of node but issue is same in all versions.

The "type": "module" is also included in the package.json.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --inspect ./index.js`
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/05b29298-95ff-4a2d-8445-64d74fad50b2
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
(node:34452) ExperimentalWarning: The Node.js specifier resolution flag is experimental. It could change or be removed at any time.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
node:internal/errors:465
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'd:'
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at throwIfUnsupportedURLScheme (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1120:11)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1200:3)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:580:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:294:18)
    at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:380:22)
    at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:106:35)
    at importModuleDynamicallyCallback (node:internal/process/esm_loader:35:14)
    at loadModel (file:///D:/Storage/backend/models/index.js:32:31)
    at file:///D:/Storage/backend/models/index.js:37:20 {
  code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

### Folder Structure:

backend:

```
- package.json

- models

    - index.js

    - users.js

    - services.js
```

...etc

package.json file

```
  "type": "module",
  "description": "Project",
  "main": "./index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "nodemon --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --inspect ./index.js",
    "start": "node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node ./index.js"
  },
```

File: models > index.js

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize'
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

import config from '../config.cjs'

const { DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DB_PORT } = config

const db = new Sequelize(
  DB_NAME,
  DB_USER,
  DB_PASSWORD,
  {
    port: DB_PORT,
    host: DB_HOST,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    underscored: true,
    underscoredAll: true,
    timestamps: false,
    timezone: Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
  }
)

db.loadModels = async () => {
  const models = await Promise.all(
    fs.readdirSync(path.resolve('models'))
      .reduce((acc, file) => {
        if (file !== 'index.js') {
          const modelPath = path.resolve('models', file)

          const loadModel = async () => {
            const modelFile = await import(modelPath)
            const model = await modelFile.default(db, DataTypes)
            return model
          }

          acc.push(loadModel())
        }
        return acc
      }, []))

  await Promise.all(models.map(({ associate }) => associate(db.models)))
  return models
}

export default db
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is for this line in `models/index.js`:

```
  const modelFile = await import(modelPath)
```

`modelPath` on Windows is an absolute file path starting with `d:\`, according to the error message:

> Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'd:'

`import` accepts URLs only, so you have to use [pathToFileURL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlpathtofileurlpath) to make it work:

```
import { pathToFileURL } from 'url';

...

const modelFile = await import(pathToFileURL(modelPath))
```

see also https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/31710